# Creating n amount of array lists

Tags: java

Right now I have an array list named "ID" that contains a list of numbers like:

```
3  3  3  3  3  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  8  8  8
```

ID will be different every time the program runs.

Is there a way that I can create a situation where I can break down my "ID" array list into smaller array lists that only contain the same number?  I cannot figure a way to create code that can make a certain number of new Array Lists based off of how many different numbers are in "ID".

```
ArrayList<Double> ID = new ArrayList<Double>();
//ID is filled by a text file that will vary but will look something like 
    // 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 (all whole numbers)
```

What I would like

```
ArrayList<Double> newArray1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
//contains 2 2 2 2 2 2 
ArrayList<Double> newArray2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
//contains 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
ArrayList<Double> newArray3 = new ArrayList<Double>();
//contains 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

and so on

Comment: you lost me halfway while reading your "question"

Comment: Do you realize that the most important piece of information is missing: how do you determine how many lists a file needs?

Comment: pretty much i am trying to make a loop where I can make X amount of array lists based on a number that will vary in the program.  FOr example, one time I run the code I may need 4 array lists and another time I run the code I may need 7.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it is impossible to know *why* your program does not work as expected.

Comment: @assylias, Not true! Let me go get my crystal ball. BRB!

Comment: Take the example you gave and give us an example output for it.

Comment: Also, please take the code dump you gave us and generate a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Remove anything not related to your question - it will make it easier to help.

Comment: That sure clear it up !

Answer (score 1):

To have unique values, use a `Set` and let java do the work.

To know, at any time, how many values of each kind you have, you may use a `Map<Integer,Integer>`.

Comment: +1 for the `Map<Integer, Integer>`. Best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

> smaller array lists that only contain the same number?

So you want to have an arraylist filled with elements witch are all equal? Why would you do that??

You could achieve what you want by using just a counter for each number. You can then save all counters in a `Map`.

```
Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
```

And for counting an ID you could have a method that looks like this:

```
public void incrementForID(String id, Map<String, Integer> countMap) {
    Integer c = countMap.get(id);
    if(c == null) {
         c = 0;
    }
    coutmap.put(id, c.intValue()+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OhMyGod {

    public List<ArrayList<Object>> answerThisQuestion(List<File> files) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();

        for (File f: files) {
            int numberOfLists = magicallyGuessHowMany(f);
            for (int i = numberOfLists -1; numberOfLists != 0; numberOfLists--) {
                returnValue.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    public int magicallyGuessHowMany(File f){
        // answer my question here
    }
}
```

I guess this will not adress your *need*. However, it answers your *question*.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use `List<ArrayList<MyObject>>`.

Therefore you can add as many `ArrayList` as you want.